# rfkill* LED triggers. What does it mean?

Tags: board-leds

```
$ cat /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger
none rc-feedback kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock   
kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock   
kbd-ctrlrlock timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 default-on   
input panic [mmc1] mmc0 rfkill-any rfkill-none rfkill0
```

I find a couple of LED triggers that I can't find their function of.

They are `rfkill0`  `rfkill-none`  and `rfkill-any`.

Who can explain their subtle differences? Please do.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is of course failing, but as I understood it:

```
rfkill0             Flash on wifi activity
rfkill1             Flash on bluetooth activity
rfkill-any          Flash on any activity (wifi or bluetooth)
rfkill-none         Never understood that one
```